# How to structure PHP classes

Tags: php, class, oop

In file A,

```
Class A {
   __construct() {
          ...
      lots of code 
          ...
  }

  public function P() {
      code here
  }
}
New A();
```

In file B,

```
Class B {
   __construct() {
          ...
      lots of code 
          ...
  }

  public function E() {
      I need to call function P in Class A
  }
}
New B();
```

I would like to call the function `P()` in function `E()`.

Is there any way to call a function in another class?

I found several ways such as dependency injection using `__construct( A $aobj )` or "extends"

However, the `class A` was already instantiated in file A and there're a lot of things in `__counstruct` so I would like to know

1) the way of refractory technique

2) fancy way to call function `E()` in function `P()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how class B is related to A :

- no link : the function in A should be static (it doesn't interact with a specific instance of `A` and its properties), and you can call `A::P()`
- the class B is a child of A :

In B class definition, you have a `class B extends A` and in the constructor of B, you will have a `parent::__construct()` to call the constructor of A.
Then you can simply call `$this->P()`  : as B is a subclass of A, and `P` is public (or protected), B inherits of all methods from A

- The class B uses a object of type A`

Then, you must have a `$a` attribute in the class B, and a `$this->a = new A();` in the constructor of B. You can call `P` with `$this->a->P();`

Or if you need only temporarily `A` in `E()`, you can construct a new object `$a = new A();` and call `$a->P();` in the code of `E`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!! :) It helps a lot! Can I ask you a question? In case of "no link", why it should be 'static'?

Comment: So you can call the function without having to instantiate an object, which can take a lot of resource (which seems to be the case in your example). If you don't have to manipulate the internal state of a specific object, a static method allows you to have a result without going through the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!  I really appreciate it :) I moved the most of the actions from __construct of A for the performance of instantiate class A and used the last method because function P needs some item of __construct. Therefore, I could not use the static function P. Thank you and I've learned a lot from you :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that we have file a.php which contains class A:

```
class A {

  public function __construct()
  {

  }

  public function P()
  {
    echo "It is function P";
  }
}
```

And file b.php which contains class B, in file b.php we first include a.php

```
include('a.php');
class B {

  private $aobj;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->aobj = new A();
  }

  public function E(){
    $this->aobj->P();
  }
}

$b = new B();
$b->E();
```

Now open the browser and http://localhost/your-project/b.php and see the result.